# What is the best way to modify the email signature in PHPBB

Tags: email, phpbb

I need to add some text into emails sending from PHPBB forum.
I have found email templates (more than 30). So I can see 3 ways to do that:
1. Add the static text into every template. Probably this is not the best solution.
2. Modify the variable EMAIL_SIG. It is added for most templates (I see 31 of 34). But if I understand it right(?) it demands to modify the core method messenger::send() where that variable content is set. Or it can be set via the admin interface?
3. Create the new variable and to add it to the needed templates. But unfortunately I don't know how to do it right.
Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add an email signature via your ACP...

```
ACP -> General -> Client communication -> E-mail settings -> E-mail signature
```